# Reference for the subgroup structure of $\rm{PSL}_2(q)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

This material is covered in detail in Dickson's "Linear Groups with an exposition of the Galois Field Theory", chapter XXII and Huppert's "Endliche Gruppen", chapter II, paragraph 8. Since I don't speak german and Dickson's treatment often requires deciphering, I was wondering if there is a "modern" account of this somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some [notes](http://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/o.h.king/KingBCC05.pdf) by Oliver King containing a statement of the full classification in modern terms.  However, this expository paper does not derive the result.  A standard reference for the subgroup structure of classical groups is the [book](http://books.google.ca/books/about/The_subgroup_structure_of_the_finite_cla.html?id=Umc4AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Kleidman and Liebeck, but I don't recall that they cover Dickson's full list.  They focus on maximal subgroups.  The exposition there is rather, shall we say, "efficient".

Answer (score 9):

Suzuki's Group Theory (I) 3.§6 page 392-418 is modern and very clear.  The main theorem is on page 404, which coincidentally is the error code from google books for [its page scan](http://books.google.com/books?id=eD-icQAACAAJ&pg=PA404).

Comment: Thanks. I keep wondering why no one has ever translated Huppert's book though.

Answer (score 2):

Two other modern references for the maximal subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ are:  Bray, Holt and Roney-Dougal, The maximal subgroups of the low-dimensional finite classical groups, London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, vol. 407, 2013, and Michael Giudici, Maximal subgroups of almost simple groups with socle ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, [arXiv:math/0703685](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703685).

Answer (score 2):

It's also covered in Gorenstein's *Finite Groups* (ironically enough, also in section 8 of chapter 2, just like Huppert, but I think this is coincidence).

Answer (score 0):

B. Huppert, Endliche Gruppen I, Springer, Berlin, 1967.

Comment: That choice was already dismissed in the question.