# Order of matrices in $SL_2({\mathbb{F}_q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Could you tell me how to prove that in $SL_2({\mathbb{F}_q})$ the only element of even order is $-I$ ($ \ I$ - identity  matrix)?

I would really appreciate a thorough explanation, because I cannot find anything on my own.

[Here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT310.pdf), page 29, is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 5):

It is false. For every element $g$ of odd order, $(-I)\cdot g$ must have even order.

Answer (score 4):

Not true. Take $q = 5$, for instance, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has order $4$.

More generally, your group has order
$$
\frac{(q^2 -1) (q^2 - q)}{q-1} = (q-1) q (q+1),
$$
so for $q$ odd you see a Sylow $2$-subgroup has order at least $8$.

(I'm only thinking of elements of order a power of $2$, then see **user53845**'s answer.)

> **Addendum**

The real question appears to be that $-I$ is the unique element of order $2$. Such an element must have two eigenvalues equal to $-1$, and then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^{2}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \ne I.
$$
($q$ odd assumed throughout, see the post of **Marc van Leeuwen**.)

Comment: But note that such Sylow subgroup could be elementary abelian and contain only elements of order 2. (Maybe there is a nice argument why it isn't?)

Comment: @Myself $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}^{2} = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ for $q$ odd.

Comment: [apparently](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170329/sylow-2-subgroups-of-the-group-mathrmpsl2-q) a Sylow 2 subgroup of SL(2,q) is always a generalized quaternion group.

Comment: @Myself, I was just writing this, it depends on the fact that $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ is the *only* involution.

Comment: Could you take a look at the link I've just added?

Comment: @Andrew, sure, it says, as we were discussing in the comments, that $-I$ is the only element of order $2$.

Comment: Could you tell me in what way eigenvalues of a matrix determine its order in this group?

Comment: @Andrew, sure. If $a^2 = I$, then $a$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2 - 1$, so $a$ has eigenvalues in $\{1, -1\}$, but it has to be two $-1$, because $\det(a) = 1$ and $a \ne I$.

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you, I didn't realize that :)

Answer (score 2):

The text only says that $-I$ is the unique element of order $2$, not the only element of even order. Even this is not quite true, but it is true in characteristic different from $2$, since there all involutions (elements of order$~2$) in $GL(n)$ are diagonalisable (being annihilated by the polynomial $X^2-1=(X+1)(X-1)$ that is split with simple roots), and for $n=2$ this can only mean there is one eigenvalue $1$ and one eigenvalue $-1$, so the determinant is $-1$ one one is not in $SL(2)$.

However in characteristic $2$ any element of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ has order $2$ and determinant$~1$, and is not a multiple of the identity if $x\neq0$.

Comment: Could you explain to me, then, this part of the proof in the text : "there exist elements $a$ and $b$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $a, \ b, \ ab$ have orders $2m, \ 2n, \  2r$ respectively. As $-I$ is the
unique element of order $2$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, the images of $a, \ b, \ ab$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q) \setminus \{+-I \}$ will then
have orders $m,  \ n, \ r$ as required." Why can we divide the orders by 2?

Comment: The last step is just dividing out the center of order $2$ from $SL_2(\Bbb F_q)$ (with $q$ odd) giving the group $PSL_2(\Bbb F_q)$. For any $g\in SL_2(\Bbb F_q)$ of order $2n$, the power $g^n$ has order $2$, so equals $-I$, and its image in $PSL_2(\Bbb F_q)$ is the identity. The image of $g$ in $PSL_2(\Bbb F_q)$ then has order $n$.

Comment: I hope you're still there. I just want to make sure I understand you correctly. The order of an element $a$ in a quotient group divides its order in the whole group. By Lagrange theorem, $|G|=|N||G/N|$. Since the order of $N$ is in this case $2$, this means that the order of $G/N$ is two times less. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite, at least not if you mean by $G$ the whole group. The order of (the image of) $a$ in the quotient does always divide that of $a$, but the number to divide by is the order of _the intersection_ of $N$ with the group $\langle a\rangle$ of powers of $a$ (which might be $\{e\}$ even if $N$ isn't). But in the particular situation considered, the only nontrivial element of $N$ is $-I$, and being _the only element of $G$ of order $2$_ this element lies in _every cyclic subgroup of $G$ of even order_. It is this latter circumstance that ensures that all even orders get halved in the quotient

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. Thank you.