# Subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ of order $2q$

Tags: finite-groups, classical-groups

Let $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Is it true that $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ has a unique class of conjugate subgroups of order $2q$?

I looked at the references that appear in [this MO question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/reference-for-the-subgroup-structure-of-psl2-q), the only relevant refernce there is Oliver King's [notes](http://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/o.h.king/KingBCC05.pdf) where he cites the classification given in Dickson's book. The classification theorem there has $22$ items (items (a) to (v)), and it appears that the only item where a subgroup of order $2q$ can appear is item (m), but the description of that item is very mysterious:

> (m) a number of classes of conjugate groups of order $q_0d$ for each divisor $q_0$ of $q$ and for certain $d$ depending on $q_0$, all lying inside a group of order $q(q − 1)/2$ for $q$ odd and $q(q − 1)$ for $q$ even;

Using GAP I checked all appropriate $q$'s up to $100$ and in these cases there is a unique conjugacy class of subgroups of order $2q$, isomorphic to $D_{2q}$ when $q$ is prime; and isomorphic to $(C_p)^e\rtimes C_2$ when $q=p^e$. Is this a general fact?  If so, is there a nice interpretation of this subgroup, such as the stabilizer in $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ of something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $B$ denote the normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G = {\rm PSL}(2,q)$, where $q = p^{a}$ for the odd prime $p.$ Then $B$ may be taken as the image (mod $\pm I$ of the group of upper triangular matrices of determinant $1.$ Let $M$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $2q$. Then $M$ has a normal $2$-complement, which is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G.$ Since we are only concerned with $M$ up to conjugacy, we my suppose that $U$ is a common Sylow $p$-subgroup of $B$ and $M.$ Note that this places $M$ inside $B$ as $U \lhd M.$ Now a complement to $U$ in $B$ is the image of the diagonal matrices of determinant $1,$ which is cyclic. Now $B/U$, being cyclic, has a unique subgroup of order $2$. Hence $B$ has a unique subgroup of order $2|U|$ by the isomorphism theorems. Hence this must be $M.$ In other words, in general, every subgroup of $G$ of order $2|U|$ is $G$-conjugate to the unique subgroup of $B$ of order $2|U|$. This is the image (mod scalars) of the group of upper triangular matrices of determinant $1$ with (not necessarily) primitive $4$-th roots of unity on the diagonal.