# Does $SL(2, \mathbb F_p)$ always have a subgroup of order $(p-1)(p+1)$?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, finite-groups, finite-fields

For $p$ prime, does $SL(2, \mathbb F_p)$ always have a subgroup of order $(p-1)(p+1)$? (It does seem to be the case for $p=3,5,7,11$)

If yes, what are the generators?

I guess this is simple, but my group theory is really rusty.
Thanks!

Comment: The answer is no in general. In fact $2,3,5,7,11$ are the only prime powers for which there is such a subgroup.

Comment: @Derek: Thanks! Is there some simple proof, or some references you could give? Btw I would accept your comment as an answer

Comment: The only way I know of proving that is to look at the complete list of subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$. There are some references for that in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021