# Generators of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Do the row operations that preserve the determinant generate the special linear group over the field with p elements (p is a prime)?
In other words are the matrices: \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix} generators for $SL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Comment: Gorenstein's Finite Groups and Hupperts Endliche Gruppen, Vol I contain extensive discussion of the structure of SL(2,p) and related groups (in section 8 of chapter 2 in both cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$ and $T=\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}$. To show these
generated $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb F_p)$, all you need to do is to prove that
if $A\in \text{SL}_2(\Bbb F_p)$ then one can left-multiply $A$ by a sequence
of $S$s and $T$s and arrive at the identity.

Let $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$. Then multiplying on the left by $I$ or $T$
will give a matrix $\pmatrix{a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1}$ with $c_1\ne0$. Now
multiplying by a suitable power of $S$ gives a matrix $\pmatrix{1&b_2\\c_2&d_2}$. Multiplying by $T^{-c_2}$ gives $\pmatrix{1&b_3\\0&1}$.
Finally multiply by $S^{-b_3}$ to get to the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true.  Gorenstein says this is due to Dickson.  It's on p. 44 of Gorenstein's *Finite Groups* as Theorem 8.4

If you want as much detail as you like, both Gorenstein's *Finite Groups* and Hupperts *Endliche Gruppen, Vol I* contain extensive discussion of the structure of $SL(2,p)$ and related groups (in section 8 of chapter 2 in both cases).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have access to the texts you referenced, and I (of course) would like some justification as to why the statement is true. Could you give some justification, or link me to a good source? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately the proof is not so short that it would be fair use to reproduce it here.  This seems to have been asked here before and I will post that as a separate link since other sources are mentioned (but, for whatever reason, not Gorenstein). Probably the easiest thing to do though is to search on something like "dickson sl2p".  That got me right to the necessary pages of Gorenstein (44-46) on Google books.

Comment: The other related thread on MSE is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/reference-for-the-subgroup-structure-of-psl2-q?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa