# Subgroups of ${\rm PGL}(2, \mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: group-theory, general-linear-group

Final Goal: Given $p$, an odd prime, and $\mathbb F_p$, the corresponding finite field, enumerate the subgroups of $G=\mathrm{PGL}(2,  \mathbb{F}_p)$, $H < G$, such that $|G|/|H|$ is odd.

Harder but seemingly doable goal: Given $p$ being an odd prime, enumerate the subgroups of $G=\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb F_p)$.

Speculative idea: Maybe one can translate the result from the classification result of $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb C)$ to $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb F_p)$.

Comment: I doubt you can translate the classification result, since the characteristic is different.

Comment: Burnside classified all subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$, and it is routine to use this to do the same for ${\rm PGL}(2,p)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That sounds interesting. What is the reference for the case of $\mathrm{PSL}(2, q)$?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/)