# Perfect Subgroups of $GL(2,p)$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, general-linear-group

It is known that $SL(2,p)$ is a perfect subgroup of $GL(2,p)$ if $p>3$. My question is:

Are they the only perfect subgroups of $GL(2,p)$?

If not, can $GL(2,p)$ have perfect subgroups whose order is not divisible by $p$?

Comment: Your questions are phrased as isolated problems, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the classification of subgroups of $PSL(2,p)$ by Dickson, see [Reference for the subgroup structure of $\rm{PSL}_2(q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/reference-for-the-subgroup-structure-of-rmpsl-2q), the only perfect subgroups of $SL(2,p)$ can be

- The trivial subgroup
- $SL(2,p)$ itself
- $SL(2,5)\cong 2.A_5$. These arise for $p\equiv \pm1\pmod{10}$, thus $p=11$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are these three subgroups, the only perfect subgroups of $GL(2,p)$?

Comment: @cryptomaniac Any perfect subgroup of $GL$ must lie in $SL$, as $\det[A,B]=\det(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})=1$.